# Firing OnClick on TextBox using JQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a textbox in which anytime user clicks on it a function in the code behind needs to get fired. Here is the JQuery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $("#txtName").click(function(){<%TextChanged();%>});

    </script>
```

And here is the Textbox UI:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

And here is the code behind of TextChanged() function in which I am running some query:

```
protected void TextChanged()
    {
        //Writing my query here!!!
    }
```

Now this function is firing up in the Page_Load() not in txtName.Click. Why? I want to fire this TextChanged() function from JQ whenever user is clicking on the txtName!

Comment: I don't see any Ajax here; you're wanting the client side text box click to execute server side code?

Comment: You'll need to use some ajax and then provide a response from the server. I'd recommend ajax and perusing some of the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked a very similar question to this not too long ago. The problem is that without some fairly gnarly jury-rigging, this isn't going to work well. Running server-side code every time there is text changed in that textbox is going to provide for a poor user experience, as the page will postback every time text gets changed. So every time a users hits a key, boom, the page disappears, reappears, and then they have to find the textbox again if you do not set focus.

You really need to handle whatever it is that you are doing on the clientside through JavaScript/jQuery. What is your end goal? What are you wanting to happen when text gets changed?

Comment: I am actually running Linq2Sql and from that query I am populating 2 another text boxes. So I am guessing this will be hard on client side scripting or using jQuery!

Comment: Not really. You are going to need to do as others suggested: use AJAX. Basically, you will need to set up a web service that you can call via jQuery. This will enable you to handle the textbox changes without a postback, as jQuery calling the web service will handle all of your interaction needs without requiring a postback.

It will go something like this:

Comment: 1. Textbox changed
2. jQuery captures the change event
3. jQuery fires off an AJAX request to a web service with the value of the textbox
4. The web service does its processing and creates the return value(s)
5. jQuery receives the values from the services and fills the other textboxes as appropriate.

Comment: Cool Steve. Can you provide me with some link or anything...I am new in these things...

Comment: http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx

One thing you could do is change your server-side code from Text_Changed to a more appropriate name and make it a PageMethod (basically, a web service that is built right into the page's code behind). The link I provided walks you through all of that.

Answer (score 0):

Server side code `<%TextChanged();%>` gets executed when the page is pulled the first time. The onclick function triggers on the client side and cannot do anything on the server side. You need to use postback somehow. Use AJAX via jQuery or ASP.NET's AJAX using page methods, web services etc.

Here is a short demonstration to explain what goes on. Create an aspx page and have this in it

```
<html>
    <body>

        <script language="javascript">
        function ShowTime()
        {
            alert('<%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %>');
        }
        </script>

        <form runat="server">

            <asp:TextBox runat="server" onclick="ShowTime();" Text="Click Me"></asp:TextBox>

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Then pull it in the browser and click the textbox a few times. You should see the same alert everytime. Check the rendered HTML (view source)

```
<html>
    <body>

        <script language="javascript">
        function ShowTime()
        {
            alert('4/20/2011 12:06:09 PM');
        }
        </script>

        <form method="post" action="Test1.aspx" id="ctl00">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJLTU2Mzk2MTc5ZGTwB2Ph3lGOb1/uUI+lbZ5QtQQT2kk+dPbtprtjMpSZBg==" />
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWAgK946tbAqLAiY0L0tc9fkAJ/FKqRuxYl8nrpx8irMZ96Kzc8GjJhrrhP9A=" />

</div>

            <input name="ctl01" type="text" value="Click Me" onclick="ShowTime();" />

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see the server side code `DateTime.Now.ToString()` has already executed and it has sent the time at the moment of execute to the client browser. Now no matter how many times the client side function is executed, the same time would be alerted as there is no communication going on between client and server.

Comment: Yea, I wanted to do that using WebServices. How can I do that? Any link...Please!

Comment: Start with page methods and then move to web services.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle the click event on the client side you should implement code in the 
JQuery function not on the server side

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it doesn't quite work like that -- you can't fire a server event from the front-end without either doing a post-back or using AJAX.  Second of all, .NET assigns it's own, server-generated ID's to WebForms elements, so you're not selecting the txtName element at all.  Try using the `CssClass` property and using something like `$(".myElement").click(function() { });`

If you want to be able to fire off a server event using a front-end instantiated event asynchronously, your best bet is to use an AJAX call.  Otherwise, just do a post-back.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on asp but this kind of services works similar. When get a request for your page the server process it and construct a result html from your asp file. This html is processed by the browser. So when you put <%TextChanged();%> on your asp file your server executed and send the corresponding result. Actually your jquery script looks like this on the browser

```
$("#txtName").click(function(){});
```

For this to work you need to send a new request to the server to execute your TextChanged method on server and returns a valid response (xml for example) so the browser or in this case your jquery script can handle it and show the info you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the AutoPostBack feature?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" 
             runat="server" 
             AutoPostBack="true" 
             OnTextChanged="TextChanged" />
```

Comment: I don't really know why all these answers think this is such a difficult task, it's obviously a VERY easy thing to do in .NET.  Furthermore, if you wanted to fire it manually from JavaScript you could use `__doPostBack("txtName","");`. **Edit - you would need to make sure "txtName" was the uniqueId for `__doPostBack` to work.**